# jquery dialog: dragging dialog with iframe inside

Tags: jquery, dialog, draggable

When dragging a jquery dialog with an iframe inside , the drag stops if the mouse goes over the frame contents while dragging. It seems that the iframe takes automatically the focus.
is there any way to prevent this and make drag normal?

```
var iframe=document.createElement('IFRAME');    
$(div).append(iframe)
       .dialog();
```

Comment: Not sure of a simple fix, but the reason it happens is because that `<iframe>` is getting the `mousemove` event, and it's not bubbling up to the parent `document` on the main page.

Comment: This problem occurs with any draggable div with an IFRAME inside it (or where there are IFRAMEs nearby and you move the mouse quickly over those nearby IFRAMEs). I'd imagine that if there is an easy fix, it would already be implemented in jQuery automatically! But would be happy to be proved wrong. Note that the drag operation resumes correctly when you move back off the IFRAME, so it's not exactly broken. It works okay.

Comment: I tried drag:function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); } in the dialog option
but it doen't work. 
yes the drag operation resumes correctly when mouse goes out iframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just my guess, but I'd try covering everything with a transparent div 100% width&height while dragging and assuring it's above iframes and under the dragged thingie :)

Comment: It works, but obviously blocks the interaction with the iframe.

Comment: @Guglie I clearly stated it should only be covered while dragging. You won't be able to drag things and drop them into iframed documents anyway (not possible with any existing drag-n-drop implementation). A custom made solution could do that if it communicated between the windows, but making it smooth could be hard, if not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

from naugtur suggestion i found this good working solution:

```
dragStart:function(){
    var divt=document.createElement('div');
    $(divt).attr('id','tempdragdiv');
     divt.style.height='93%';
    divt.style.width='100%';
    $(divt).css('position','absolute').css('left','0')  .css('top','0');                    
    $(div).append(divt);//div where is iframe
    },
    dragStop:function(){
        $('#tempdragdiv').remove();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the same solution with accepted one, only this one gives sample code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting a z-index for the iframe?

```
var iframe=document.createElement('IFRAME');    
iframe.css('z-index', '-999');
$(div).append(iframe)
       .dialog();
```