# jQuery UI Draggable div sticks to mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a div as a popup which is draggable as follows

```
$("#popup").draggable();
```

The problem is if we mouseclick on this div and leave the click, then the div sticks to the mouse in some IE versions, especially on Windows 7. The div moves with the mouse even if its not click & drag action (its just a mouseover action). Please let me know if this is jQuery bug or some OS/browser bug with proper solution?

I am using jquery-ui-1.8.6 js with jquery-1.4.2 js.

Comment: Are you trying to drag an iframe?

Comment: The draggable div is inside an Iframe. To be exact, its one of the child element of iframe.

Comment: The event listeners is registered in the inner page, when you move the mouse to the outer page the listeners can not be triggered. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388868/jquery-dialog-dragging-dialog-with-iframe-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will recommend you to use the latest versions of both jquery-ui and jquery library file..

the code you provide has not much enough to be debate about but as you mentioned, it could be because of the older version of files.

i am using latest versions of both files (jquery-ui-1.8.21/jquery-1.7.1) and dragging is working fine in all ie versions.

but when you are using iframes, things went little different. because some browsers specially ie handles iframes differently, i might be guessing but it could be the case! :)